# How and when are python @properties evaluated

Tags: python, properties, python-internals

Here's a snippet of code.

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        print("calling init")

    @property
    def b(self):
        b = "b"
        print("in property")
        return b

test_obj = TestClass()
print("a = {} b = {}".format(test_obj.a,test_obj.b))
```

I'm trying to understand **when** the variable *b* defined inside test_obj gets its value of "b".

As you can see from the below screenshot, the statement on line 13 is yet to be evaluated/executed but already the value of *b* for test_obj has been initialized. Debugging this by placing a breakpoint on literally every single line didn't help me understand how this is happening.

[image]
Can someone please explain this to me ?

Comment: This is probably going to be specific to what the *IDE* is doing, not Python itself. The method will get called on access to the `b` attribute of an instance of `TestClass`, but it looks like the IDE is doing that in the background for the debugger output.

Comment: The code in the function `b` only gets run when you access that attribute. For example if `b` raised an exception your code would be fine until you accessed `test_obj.b` specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More likely, the IDE is trying to show you what the value of `test_obj.b` is. For that it *gets the value from `test_obj.b`*. Since it doesn't make much of a difference whether `b` is an attribute or a `@property`, the debugger essentially just does `test_obj.b` for you, which gives it the value `'b'`.

The function `def b` works exactly as you might expect from any other ordinary function; it's just that the debugger/IDE implicitly invokes it for you.

Comment: So the value for test_obj.b would be retrieved only when it's called time anytime and every single time, here, in this snippet of code, it's just once at line 13, correct ?

Comment: Yes, without a debugger, that value wouldn't exist yet at that time.